# TYPO3: Show language names for default language in speaking URL using RealURL

Tags: seo, search-engine, typo3, multilingual, realurl

I set up a TYPO3 website using TYPO3 4.7. The website is bilingual (German/English) and the are 'speaking' using RealURL.
The default language is German.

So far it works nicely. I get URLs like:

> http://www.mywebsite.something/neuigkeiten
>
> http://www.mywebsite.something/kontakt

If the user changes the language to English, he gets URLs like:

> http://www.mywebsite.something/en/news
>
> http://www.mywebsite.something/en/contact

If the changes the language back to German, he gets URLs like:

> http://www.mywebsite.something/de/neuigkeiten
>
> http://www.mywebsite.something/de/kontakt

The problem is: This creates duplicates for search engines. So, I would like the default language also to use the language parameter for German 'de' as a default in the URLs before the user changes the language.

Does anyone had the same problem before?

Thank you, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to define dafault language in realurl config.
Smth like this should be enough:

```
array(
    'GETvar' => 'L',
    'valueMap' => array(
        'en' => '1',
        ),
        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
      )
```